# How to start local AEM 6.5 instance on port 4502 using Docker

Tags: powershell, docker, localhost, docker-for-windows, adobe-experience-manager

I'm using the latest Adobe Experience Manager (AEM) image in Docker (https://hub.docker.com/r/aemdesign/aem) on my Windows 10 machine and everything was working fine, but suddenly AEM no longer loads (localhost:4502). The Docker Dashboard indicates it's running.

I tried the following in PowerShell, but got an error:

```
PS C:\> docker run --name author -e "AEM_RUNMODE=-Dsling.run.modes=author,crx3,crx3tar,dev" -p4502:8080 -p30303:58242 -d aemdesign/aem

docker: Error response from daemon: open \\.\pipe\docker_engine_linux: The system cannot find the file specified.

See 'docker run --help'.
```

I've searched for a solution, but can't figure out what's going on. Has anyone had this happen or know how to get localhost:4502 working again?

Comment: did you try restarting?

Comment: Yes, I tried restarting many times.

Comment: I meant restart Docker for Windows?

Comment: Yes, I've restarted Docker many times and then opened the Dashboard and clicked the Start icon for the aemdesign/aem container, but it's not accessible at localhost:4502.